# str.extract giving error: SettingWithCopyWarning

Tags: python, regex

I am try to create a new dataframe column based on job_num. I want to extract a 8-10 digit number starting with 9 using regex. The code I have works except I am getting the error:

> 'SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
>   slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] =
>   value instead'

I know it has to do with copying instead of referencing but can't figure out how to do it.

```
bonus2['job'] = bonus2.loc[:,'job_num'].str.extract(r'(9\d{7,9})', expand = True)
```

Ideally I would like to have a new column created to the dataframe.

Comment: settingwithcopy warning just tells you that you are modifying the original dataframe. This is because of your expand paramater. You can create a new dataframe and thus you won't see this warning.